# Intellij unable to configure and view files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I changed my 2017 Intellij version to 2018.2 version on my Mac. All my previous configurations are not working now. Thus started todo everything. But I am hardy able to do anything. It is extremely buggy where there is no responses to button clicks when I configure, and under the file structure, it is just stuck on loading. I have tried to restart the laptop and invalid cache/ restart which makes no difference.

Is there a way around this? Absolutely regretting making the change from 2017 version. Please refer to images. Thanks.

Stuck on loading under project structure.

[image]

Trying to reconfigure. Clicking on fix bubble gives me option to choose war file. I usually click the exploded option and it would just configure. Right now clicking the exploded or non exploded option does nothing. The fix bubble just stays on.

[image]

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: Does it still work in the 2017 version? I'm not sure even what questions to ask, but it looks like youre trying to talk to a JBoss server which means youre using IJ Ultimate, so it sounds like youre a paying customer and would be entitled to tech support.

Comment: try to import again the project. Is it the same in another project?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Issue raised: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204110

Comment: @Cadeq It is the same for this project. I have actually cloned a fresh git version of the project and rebuilt everything and tried again. Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed copy identified to be corrupted. The issue is resolved by downloading and using version 2018.3.1